# Trouble logging into mysql as non root

Tags: mysql

I logged into mysql as root and then entered the following code:

`grant select, insert, update, delete, index, alter, create, drop
on books.*
to bookorama identified by 'new';`

Then I log out of mysql and when I try to log back in and enter new for password, I get an error
and the window of mysql closes.  I am using this on Windowns 7.  How would I log in as the new user I created?

Figured it out, when I downloaded mysql I needed to check the box allowing commands from  the command line, then I type mysql -h hostname username -p.  hit enter and I am in mysql as a new user.  Thanks you for the help

Comment: Have you actually created the "bookorama" user account prior to this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: yes and no.  I tried it without bookorama being created before then with bookoram being created, then I deleted bookorama and tried again.  I could not read the error, the console, flashes and error and then closes.

Comment: Have you enabled logging in MySQL, if so you can read the error in the MySQL log. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the mysql console from a command prompt - that way the window won't close before you've had a chance of reading the error message.

Comment: I am, when I opend the command line it asks for a passord when I enter a new password( not the root password) it closes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 grant select, insert, update, delete, 
       index, alter, create, drop on books.* to 
       'bookorama'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Comment: Can you log on as root, run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user\G` and provide us with the output?