# Logging in as a different user on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I created a different user, when I try to log into mysql it will not let me.  I think I am missing a step. I am using windows 7.  When I log in it automatically asks me for a password.  If I enter the root password I can use mysql.  If I enter the password I have created for the user, I get an error I cannot read and the program exits.  Do I need to first login as root then somehow log in as new user.  I am very confused.  The code I used to create the new user is here:

[Trouble logging into mysql as non root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689841/trouble-logging-into-mysql-as-non-root/5690053#comment-6499191)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
>> mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

Press enter, and you'll be prompted for the password for USERNAME.

Comment: mysql>mysql -u bookorama -p,  when I hit enter it goes to the next line, when I put a ; at the end I get an error

Comment: Oh, don't do this in the mysql prompt; do it in the command prompt.

Comment: is there a way to do this in mysql prompt?

Comment: Figured it out, when I downloaded mysql I needed to check the box allowing commands from  the command line, then I type mysql -h hostname username -p.  hit enter and I am in mysql as a new user.  Thanks you for the help

Answer (score 12):

There is no mysql equivalent to Oracle's 'connect' statement in the sense that allows to switch a user once already logged in to a mysql console session.

Answer (score 1):

You may have created the new user, but not given that user sufficient permissions on the database you're trying to manage.