# How to switch users on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-cli, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

What is the windows command to switch users on MySQL?
I'm having a little problem in using MySQL on windows. I know how to create a new user and giving grants to the new user and all. But I don't know how to switch to new user from MySQL console!

Answer (score 25):

I figured out solution. There is system command, where we can execute shell command like 'ls, cd, mv, mkdir etc.. Here we can login as different user. first I logged in as  regular user.

```
[madegow@fedora20 ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
...
MariaDB [(none)]> select user()
-> ;
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> system mysql -u madegow -p
Enter password: 
...
MariaDB [(none)]> select user();
+-------------------+
| user()            |
+-------------------+
| madegow@localhost|
```

Now user got changed to madegow user.
but when you run quit/exit it will not go back to root.  we need to bare with that.

Answer (score 7):

The MySQL CLI session is bound to the user which started it. Thus, you'll have to open a new session with the desired user after you've created it and set needed grants. You can open a new session and keep the current one. Or, you can end the current session and then start new a one:

```
mysql -uUSER -p DATABASE
```

where `USER` is name of new user and `DATABASE` is database to switch to when you log on (`-p` points that you'll prompted to enter password). To exit the session, just use `exit`.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for an equivalence of the `CONNECT` command of Oracle Database and just found it with the command `\CONNECT` available on MySQL Shell (since version 5.7.12), but that's another story.

So, as said years ago by our friend [Shivakumara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5079503/shivakumara-k-madegowda), the answer is:

```
MySQL> SYSTEM mysql -u user -p
```

Which is nothing but calling an OS shell command from MySQL prompt.

Comment: Already answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690260/mysql-logging-in-as-different-user

Answer (score 1):

Creating user syntax : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

Code :

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

To switch the only way in command line is :

```
mysql -u user -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows command prompt

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\avinash>cd/
 
C:\>cd "Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u xyzzzz -p 
Enter password: ***** ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xyzzzz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u xyzzzz -p 
Enter password:
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, after login, you can switch the user to other user `john` as shown below:

```
system mysql -u john -p
```

Or:

```
SYSTEM mysql -u john -p
```

Or:

```
\! mysql -u john -p
```